# unity : alternative to Input.GetKey in a character Select

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine, multiplayer

I am trying to make a multiplayer character select screen usable with controllers only in Unity, but upon clicking a button to select a character, I need to click again a few times fast for it to work, as if there is a lag.

I am using the rewired input framework and use custom event systems to allow multiple players on one UI.

Here is my code in C#:

```
//index is given in the onclick() unity manager
    public void select (int index)
    {
        Debug.Log(index);
        //we check that index is in the range of the models list and is not equal to selected_p1/p2
        if(index == SelectCharacter.selected_p1 || index == selectedCharacter.selected_p2 ||
           index < 0 || index >= SelectCharacter.models.Count)
            return;

        //we check if the controller used is P1 and update the visual and variables
        if(Input.GetKeyDown("joystick 1 button 0"))
        {
            Debug.Log("mouse button or joystick 1 used");
            SelectCharacter.models[SelectCharacter.selectionIndex].SetActive(false);
            SelectCharacter.selected_p1 = index;
            SelectCharacter.selectionIndex = index;
            SelectCharacter.models[SelectCharacter.selectionIndex].SetActive(true);
        }

        //we check if the controller used is P2 and update the visual and variables
        if(Input.GetKeyDown("joystick 2 button 0"))
        {
            Debug.Log("joystick 2 used");
            SelectCharacter.models[SelectCharacter.selectionIndex + (SelectCharacter.models.Count / 2)].SetActive(false);
            SelectCharacter.selected_p2 = index;
            SelectCharacter.selectionIndex = index;
            SelectCharacter.models[SelectCharacter.selectionIndex + (SelectCharacter.models.Count / 2)].SetActive(true);
        }

    }
```

it worked fine as a single player select screen without the rewired and custom event system. My guess is that making a check of `Input.GetKey` or `Input.GetKeyDown` after an `OnClick()` check with the new system is not efficient because there is too much lag. I tried looking to get some sort of pressed key log and found `KeyCode` but it is a keyboard thing. Any Ideas ?

Comment: I see you are using `Input.GetKeyDown`. Does it also fail with `Input.GetKey`?

Comment: yeah the same thing I have to press repeatedly the button for it to register the key is down

Comment: Since you are using Rewired, are you able to use `player.GetButtonDown`?

Comment: My colleague working on the gameplay part has an enum or struct called player, to use It I would need to call the Rewired namespace, but seeing the documentation I have trouble understanding how to use the function, and what to put in it